# PrintStream redirected to SWT List

Tags: java, list, swt, outputstream

I am making a GUI where the output is printed to a list.

To do this, I extend the `OutputStream` class.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List;

/**
//This class extends from OutputStream to redirect output to a SWT List widget
**/
public class CustomOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    private List list;

    public CustomOutputStream(List list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {       
        // redirects data to the list
        list.add(String.valueOf((char)b));
        // scrolls the text area to the end of data
        list.select(list.getItemCount() - 1);
        list.showSelection();
        list.deselectAll();
    }
}
```

In the `main` class, the list is created and passed to an instance of `CustomOutputStream`.  A print stream is created, using the `CustomOutputStream` as an argument.  The `System.out` and `System.err` are set to use this print stream.

```
Public List list = new List(shell, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);
Public CustomOutputStream log = new CustomOutputStream(list);
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(log);
System.setOut(ps);
System.setErr(ps);
```

Data is printed to the list in the GUI, but there is one character per line! (Each list item is one character).  Additionally, data is not printed to the list as it is generated like it would to the console, it is "dumped" all at once to the list once the program finishes running.  How do I fix these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting one character per entry in the list because you are calling `list.add` for each character that is written - every call to `list.add` adds a new line to the list. You need to change the `write` code to accumulate the current line (in a `StringBuilder` for example) until you see the end of line being written and then add the whole line).

The user interface is only updated when the SWT `readAndDispatch` loop runs. So if you are running long program in the user interface thread nothing will happen until it finishes because `readAndDispatch` is not being called.

To solve this you need to run the code in a separate thread so that the user interface thread can stay responsive. Use the `Display.asyncExec` method to update the list from the background thread.

Comment: Thanks Greg. As you suggested, I accumulated the current line in a StringBuilder until I saw the end of line being written and then added the whole line.  Works great.  However, when I use the asyncExec method, one item is added to the list twice, then a null pointer exception is thrown.  Any ideas on how to fix?  I declare my CustomOutputStream, pass it it to a class that is run in a "second" thread which uses it as an argument for System.setOut, and this CustomOutputStream class is told to add items to a list that was declared in the "first" thread.

Comment: I think you will have to ask a new question showing your code.